# How to calculate Active Users in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

[Relation table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEERP.jpg) I have a fact table named Program which has the program start date and I've connected a dimension table named "Users" to it using user_key I want to show the no of users active in every month (Each user has Registered at date and last login date i want to count the users as active from their registration to their last login i.e if user 1 registered in month of jan 2023 and his last login is in the month of September 2023 i want the user to be shown active in months from jan to sept)

I copied this Dax measure from chat gpt

```
"Active Users = 
COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(
        'Users',
        'Users'[registered_at] <= MAX('Program milestone'[program_start_date])
            && 'Users'[lastlogin_createdat] >= MIN('Program milestone'[program_start_date])
            && 'Users'[lastlogin_createdat] <= MAX('Program milestone'[program_start_date])
    )
)
"
```

but the no of users are lower than expected

Comment: Do you have any relationships between `Users` and `Program milestone`? Maybe try `FILTER( ALL('Users'),... `

Comment: yes the Users and Program Milestone is connected with User_Key, No changes after this "FILTER( ALL('Users')"

Comment: Please update question with snip of data model with relevant tables (Users, Program, Program milestone, Date table? ). And are you after active users by program or overall?

Comment: I thought the way you counted active users was by doing a DISTINCTCOUNT('FactTable'[Users]) and then filtering down from there by using the distinct count as the base measure and then altering the evaluation context as necessary.